# Navegar entre vistas WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo lo siguiente, tengo una aplicación en WPF que cambia de vistas a partir de un menú así:

```
private void ListView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ListViewItem item && item.IsSelected)
            switch (item.Name)
            {
                case "ItemUnidades":
                    DataContext = new VUnidades();
                    break;
                case "ItemConductores":
                    DataContext = new VConductores();
                    break;
                case "ItemRemediacion":
                    DataContext = new VRemediacion();
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Y funciona, puedo navegar entre ellas cambiando el DataContext y me despliega la vista que deseo pero, en mi vista de Unidades tengo un formulario y al cambiar a cualquier otra vista si los campos tienen datos los borra, quiero mantenerlos no importa cuantas veces se cambien de vista, como podría evitar que se pierdan los datos? hay alguna forma de lograr esto?

Comment: Debes crear una clase Model para esa vista y crearla como variable general para guardar la info cuando  esta este activa y se cambie por otra vista, y cargar los datos para cuando esta vista se creee   new VUnidades(modeloUnidades);

Comment: Mmm, pero eso lo tendría que hacer para cada vez que se cambia de vista?
Osea que si tengo 10 Items en el menú tendría que hacerlo 10 veces?

Comment: Pues de acuerdo con tu codigo cada que cambias de vista creas un objeto vista. Puedes crear al inicio todas las vistas en tu objeto padre ListView y mostrar/ocultar la vista activa/inactiva. Tu pregunta solo se refiere a guardar datos del formulario por eso la sugerencia es guardar y cargar los datos solo para la vista formulario.

Comment: mmm si pero, me refiero al objeto VUnidades en sí, cada vez que cambie tendría que setearlo?

Comment: si miras tu codigo cada ves que cambias a unidades creas una nueva vista esa vista no tiene datos. new VUnidades();

Comment: entonces lo que dices es que le pase a través del constructor el objeto referente a MUnidades

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104708/discussion-between-acnologia-and-miguel-zarate).

Comment: Puedes crear un objeto static que sea global en tu clase de inicio de la aplicación y cargar los valores en ese objeto y cada vez que la pantalla se abra cargue esos datos y no importa si instancias tu vista cada vez que lo abres.

Comment: asi es y la variable MUnidades debe ser  estar declarada  en la clase de vista padre para que no se pierdan los valores

Comment: Excelente funcionó de maravilla, gracias compañero.